# What makes intel capable of very high clock rates?

Tags: arm, intel

What are the determining factors responsible for why Intel chips can clock at 4Ghz or higher speeds, while other processors such as ARM can't? Is it because Intel's state of the art fabs or is it the architecture of the x86? It hard to understand how a complex chip like the i7 can clock so high.

Comment: I think you may have some misconceptions about clock speed vs performance.

Comment: I edited my question. I understand the difference between clock speeds and instructions per cycle. I also understand the difference between Risc and Cisc. What I am trying to get at is why you don't see 4.5 ghz arms.

Comment: I still think this is a misconception, cortex a9 at 3.1GHz vs Core-i7-3540M at 3.0GHz with boost to 3.7GHz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main reason why ARM processors are not clocked at 4GHz is power consumption. Architecture, fabrication, etc do play a big role, but the reality is that a tablet or mobile phone needs to last as much as it can off a battery, so all those factors are designed so that power consumption will be minimized. When going for lower power consumption, you sacrifice performance because of design choices in the node, architecture etc. Higher frequency is a battery killer because:

P = CV<sup>2</sup>f

Where C is a capacitance, V is the voltage, and f is the frequency. So it varies linearly with frequency, and it's why frequency scaling is so prevalent, even in laptops.

Comment: So it may be possible to over clock an arm. I wonder what the subjective speed is like?

Comment: @user148298  See my comment on overclocking in my answer.

Comment: +1. I would word it the other way around -- when optimizing for performance at any cost, a chip designer sacrifices battery lifetime.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any one cause, but a combination of several different factors.

Power consumption in certainly one big reason, but not the only one.

Intel does aggressively pursue the latest process, and that buys it some extra performance. It's difficult to say exactly how much, but a typical claim for a new process would be about 50% increase in speed over the previous one.

Another difference is that Intel perform full custom layout to take full advantage of their own process.

Arm supply their cores in different forms under different license terms, but typically as generic "IP" to be incorporated by other companies with their own IP in mainstream ASIC processes. As such, it is more likely to be treated as a "black box" by ASIC layout tools and not as tightly optimised as a full custom design.

Hopefully someone with ASIC experience will correct this estimate : but from my FPGA experiments, careful hand placement can get about 30-50% higher performance than the tools by themselves.

Put these two factors together and it is possible that Intel's implementation of the exact same design would be about twice the speed of a generic ASIC implementation.

ARM can mitigate this by working closely with TSMC or other ASIC manufacturers to optimise their core for specific ASIC processes; I can't say how many of the ARM cores available are optimised this way.

Comment: Good answer you've touched upon all aspects area, power and speed.  Plus the full custom aspects of an Intel layout.  Intel is generally 2 - 3 generations ahead of TSMC and others in process technology, i.e. the always the best, for quite sometime.

Answer (score 1):

A significant factor is "horses for courses".
 The i7 is marvellous in a straight line drag race but can't corner at all.

Demand, power consumption, necessary cost and need are all factors.

If you really really really wanted a 4 GHz ARM somebody would sell you one relatively soon - if you wanted to pay enough.

The Freescale MCIMX535DVV2C ARM Cortex A8 is specified at 1.2 GHz [datasheet here](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/IMX53CEC.pdf) and the MCIMX6Q4AVT10AC  ARM Cortex A9 quad core at 1 GHz [datasheet here](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/IMX6DQAEC.pdf).

With CAN, EBI/EMI, ESAI, Ethernet, GPMI, I2C, MMC/SD, PCI, SATA, SPI, UART, USB, USB OTG
and peripherals dedicated to DMA, HDMI, I2S/SSI/AC97, MIPI CSI, MIMI DSI, MIPI HIS, PWM, WDT, odds are it would give an X86 i7 an immensely good run for its money in many areas where the ARM is made to be used.

Adding those as external add ons to the i7 would be "annoying" [tm], at least. At $42.50 in tube quantities for the A9 and half that for the A8 it probably makes the i7 look like a really bad deal for any application that the ARM is appropriate to.

---

**Overclocking:**

Anything can be overclocked.
Some things work perfectly when overclocked at a certain speed.
Some things **appear to** work perfectly when overclocked at a certain speed.
Some things work perfectly most of the time when overclocked at a certain speed.
For semi-random values of "most" and "appear".
YMMV, and probably will.

Answer (score 1):

Why does my washing machine not go as fast as a Ferrari?

They're built to do different jobs, both manufacturers pursue different markets and both employ different technologies. If you read up on their products you'll get more than enough info on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

An issue not really touched on by other answers is the fact that while simple processors can do every operation using a relatively small fixed sequence of steps which run at a fixed rate, such a design requires that there be enough time between steps to accommodate the worst-case propagation delays.  Subdividing operations into smaller steps will reduce the worst-case propagation for each step, allowing more steps to be performed per second, but the total time for each operation would be increased.  If an operation doesn't require as input the result of a previous operation, it may be possible for the second operation to get started well before the first one completes, but for really efficient operation requires going beyond that.  If operation #2 depends upon the result of #1, but operation #3 doesn't depend upon either of the first two, optimal performance should start operation #1, "schedule" #2, and start #3; once operation #1 completes, operation #2 can be performed.

Essentially, what happens is that while subdividing instructions into smaller pieces (necessary for achieving higher clock rates) isn't hard, doing so without adding a lot of scheduling logic would decrease the amount of useful work per cycle so much that the amount of work per second would be diminished.  The more scheduling logic one adds, the more one can shrink the worst-case propagation time without reducing the amount of useful work done per second.